# Drag'n'Drop from Outlook only for one Attachment in Qt?

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, outlook, pyside

I accept drops from Outlook in my application. Extract the filenames were a funny torture, but now I have a list of them. But if I ask for the FileContents it is always empty for messages (.msg files). And for dropped attachments I only see the content of the first one.
My environment is `only windows + python 3.3 + pyside + Qt 4.8`
I use

```
data = event.mimeData().data("FileContents")            
print(len(data))
```

How can I get the filecontent of the message type? And how drop multiple files?
There is also a type names "QWindowsMime", but I have no idea if this could help me.

// Jay

Comment: Can you please tell me how you managed to accept drops from Outlook? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, till now this is a [bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17373?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) and pyside has no QWindowsMime. I think a fix in Qt 4.x never comes, so I must wait for pyside for Qt 5.0, which has the class QWindowsMimeConverter.

// Jay